# SQL Server 2016 - Maintenance Plan to delete differential backups linked to old full backup

Tags: sql-server, maintenance-plan

We have two maintenance plans which takes care of differential and full backup.
The differential backup runs everyday and deletes backups older than 1 week. The full backup runs every Sunday and deletes any full backup older than 1 week. I am looking for a way to delete all differential backups linked to the to-be-deleted old full backup.
Thanks in advance.